# Regular Expression Help to select file_name

Tags: ruby, regex

> https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/decisv/uploads/basic_file/asset/5/part_price_data.csv?AWSAccessKeyId=???????????????&Signature=?????????&Expires=

I want to remove the file_name i.e **part_price_data.csv** from the given string

Kindly help me out

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @JackManey and Reinaldo I have tried uploads\/basic_file\/asset\/5\/(.+?\b\?) following regular expression and the programming language is Ruby

Comment: Aaaaand...what happened when you tried that regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it this way:

```
(?!.*\/)(.+?)(?=\?)
```

Demo here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?30af5

Answer (score 1):

you can extract a file name from any given url with this regex;

```
\bhttps?://[-A-Z0-9.]+/[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*/([-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(?:\?[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
/[\w_.-]*?(?=\?)|[\w_.-]*$/
```

Simple, and elegant.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
.*/([^?]+)
```

filename is in group 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with java using [String Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), however you need to specify if you are using any programming language.